# Cannot get updated state value inside event handler

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to get increased `item` inside `updateItem` handler whenever I click on window. It appears updated on the screen, but what is strange is that only initial value `0` appears inside `updateItem` event handler.

```
const TodoApp = () => {
  const [item, setItem] = React.useState(0);
  const updateItem = () => {
    console.log(item);  // always prints 0
    setItem((val) => val + 1);
  };
  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('click', updateItem);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('click', updateItem);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{item}</h2>
    </div>
  )
}
```

What is the main problem?

Thank you.

Comment: You might be interested in Dan Abramov's blog post on `useEffect`: https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason on my side.
Any value being used inside event handler gets its value from the closure where it was defined. So it only appears as its initial value.

The solution is to subscribe the event handler again whenever the state is changed,
like this:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('click', updateItem);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('click', updateItem);
    };
  }, [item]);
```

There's also another way, using ref because it always keeps the latest value.